# How to use Static Resource in testclass instead of Inserting a user

Tags: apex, unit-test

i would like to use Static Resource to insert a user in test class how could i achieve this.Pleas any one help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the detailed instructions from salesforce
on [Loading Test Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm)

Just make sure you include the required fields to create a user record.